# Can Tomcat give me different cookies for different paths?

Tags: tomcat, cookies, session-cookies

Some of the stuff i googled is pretty confusing. Basically what i want is:

- a cookie for /something
- another cookie for /someotherthing, and so on...
  without having multiple webapps...

Does anyone know where/if i can define this for Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have a Java EE application deployed in the Tomcat server. If so you can set up cookies at a request level. Basically have a servlet filter generate a cookie and send it along for each of the /URL that you are accessing.

Do keep in mind that the cookie is used to identify the request the next time around. So if you introduce a different cookie for the request .. you may not be able to identify the the requests.

Comment: Then do i just need to create cookies like here http://www.java-tips.org/java-ee-tips/java-servlet/how-to-use-cookies-in-a-servlet.html and send them with the response? I have the feeling these cookies would be somehow in parallel with Tomcat's ones, so i would like to disable Tomcat's. Also, i'm guessing your solution will give me the same session id for multiple cookies? I don't really want this, i wonder if multiple session ids are possible...